# Which the sequence of gates providing the following unitary?

Tags: quantum-gate

I am struggling with a problem which has been anticipated in a different question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34491/what-are-the-correct-gates-for-the-following-unitary-matrix) for 3 qubits. I need a sequence of gates (Pauli, controlled also), such that the unitary matrix associated with the circuit is:

$$
U = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ... \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & ... \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0  & ... \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1  & ... \\
&&... \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

that is, the identity matrix having -1 as the first entry. I have not made any attempt as I do not know exactly how to approach this problem.

---

Edit:

This can be done by first computing the matrix having -1 at the end of the diagonal and using X-gates to put that '-1' on the first diagonal entry like this:

```
nq = 4
qc = QuantumCircuit(nq)

qc.x([j for j in range(0, nq)])

qc.h(0) 
qc.mcx([j for j in range(1, nq)], 0, mode='noancilla') 
qc.h(0)

qc.x([j for j in range(0, nq)])
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it of the only element with $-1$ was the last entry (corresponding to input bits 111..1)?

Comment: Yes, it is
```
    nq = 5
    qc = QuantumCircuit(nq)

    qc.h(0)  
    qc.mcx([j for j in range(1, nq)], 0, mode='noancilla')
    qc.h(0) 
```
But I need the '-1' in the first entry

Comment: So how could you convert from 000...00 into 111...11 (and then back again afterwards?

Comment: Application of x gate to each qubit?

Comment: Oh, I see your point.